# How to convert Unicode NCR form to its original form in PHP?

Tags: php, unicode, fpdf, cjk

To avoid "monster characters", I choose Unicode NCR form to store non-English characters in database (MySQL). Yet, the PDF plugin I use (FPDF) do not accept Unicode NCR form as a correct format; it displays the data directly like:

```
&#36889;&#20491;&#19968;&#20491;&#20363;&#23376;
```

but I want it to display like:

這個一個例子

Is there any method to convert Unicode NCR form to its original form?

p.s. the meaning of the sentence is "this is an example" in Traditional Chinese.

p.s. i know NCR form wastes storage space, but it is the safest method to store non-English characters. Correct me if I am wrong. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a simpler solution, using the PHP mbstring extension.

```
// convert any Decimal NCRs to Unicode characters
$string = "&#36889;&#20491;&#19968;&#20491;&#20363;&#23376;";
$output = preg_replace_callback(
  '/(&#[0-9]+;)/u', 
  function($m){
    return utf8_entity_decode($m[1]);
  }, 
  $string
);
echo $output; // 這個一個例子

//callback function for the regex
function utf8_entity_decode($entity){
  $convmap = array(0x0, 0x10000, 0, 0xfffff);
  return mb_decode_numericentity($entity, $convmap, 'UTF-8');
}
```

The 'utf8_entity_decode' function is from PHP.net (Andrew Simpson): http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-decode-numericentity.php#48085. I modified the code slightly to avoid the deprecated 'e'-modifier within the Regex.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is very complicated.

There are 3 parts of the solution:
Part 1: Install FPDF Chinese Plug-in
Part 2: Convert NCR format to UTF-8
Part 3: Convert UTF-8 format to BIG5 (or any target encoding)

## Part 1

I fetched the FPDF Chinese Plug-in from here: http://dev.xoofoo.org/modules/content/d1/d6e/a00073.html
It is used to display Chinese characters in FPDF, and fetches all the Chinese fonts needed. To install this plug-in, just include it in PHP. (but for my case, I use another plug-in named CellPDF, which crashes with this Chinese Plug-in; thus, I have to merge the codes and resolve the conflicts)

## Part 2

To convert NCR format to UTF-8, I use the following codes:

```
function html_entity_decode_utf8($string)
{
    static $trans_tbl;

    // replace numeric entities
    $string = preg_replace('~&#x([0-9a-f]+);~ei', 'code2utf(hexdec("\\1"))', $string);
    $string = preg_replace('~&#([0-9]+);~e', 'code2utf(\\1)', $string);

    // replace literal entities
    if (!isset($trans_tbl))
    {
        $trans_tbl = array();

        foreach (get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES) as $val=>$key)
            $trans_tbl[$key] = utf8_encode($val);
    }

    return strtr($string, $trans_tbl);
}
function code2utf($num)
{
    if ($num < 128) return chr($num);
    if ($num < 2048) return chr(($num >> 6) + 192) . chr(($num & 63) + 128);
    if ($num < 65536) return chr(($num >> 12) + 224) . chr((($num >> 6) & 63) + 128) . chr(($num & 63) + 128);
    if ($num < 2097152) return chr(($num >> 18) + 240) . chr((($num >> 12) & 63) + 128) . chr((($num >> 6) & 63) + 128) . chr(($num & 63) + 128);
    return '';
}
```

which is written by laurynas butkus at php.net (link: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php)
Though this piece of code itself converts NCR format to "monster characters", I know it is a good start.

## Part 3

After I digged deep in php.net, I found a nice function: iconv, to convert encoding.
So I wrap the above codes with the following function:

```
function ncr_decode($string, $target_encoding='BIG5') {
    return iconv('UTF-8', 'BIG5', html_entity_decode_utf8($string));
}
```

Therefore, if I want to convert the previous line of NCR strings, I only need to run this function:

```
ncr_decode("&#36889;&#20491;&#19968;&#20491;&#20363;&#23376;");
```

p.s. by default, I set the target encoding to BIG5.

That's it!

Comment: If you're using PHP version >= 4.3 you should be able to replace the bulk of your code with `html_entity_decode`, which will even output in BIG5 if you tell it to. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Actually, if you'd store all your text in UTF8 (taking care that it is fetched from the database in UTF8 and handled as UTF8), all you'd need to do is convert it from UTF8 to BIG5 for output through FPDF, i.e. skip Part 2 & 3 entirely. No?

Comment: Actually I use UTF8 to store text data in MySQL, but still, weird characters still exist if part 2 & 3 are skipped.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`html_entity_decode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php).

PS: The better way would be to use UTF-8 all the way through. Search on SO for questions regarding PHP, MySQL and UTF-8, there are a few that list the possible gotchas.

Comment: under FPDF, I am afraid the solution is not that easy. I am getting close to the solution... and will post the solution here.

Comment: Hum, FPDF doesn't seem to support anything besides ISO-8859-1 (and thereby no asian characters(?)). Steven Wittens wrote an experimental extension to add UTF8 support: http://acko.net/node/56